# Visual Studio Code "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided" error

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript1.8

I'm using Visual Studio Code 0.10.6 to compile a TypeScript 1.8 (beta) project.  The editor is showing a "Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided" error:

[image: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided]

However, I have value for the `module` property in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./src/scripts/compiled",
        "rootDir": "./src/scripts"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "jspm_packages"
    ]
}
```

The project compiles without errors (I'm using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) to compile my TypeScript files), and I've restarted the editor multiple times.

**Why is Visual Studio Code showing this error, even though my code is compiling without errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code 0.10.6 hasn't build-in TypeScript 1.8 support yet.

Suppose you have install typescript 1.8 with `npm install`, add a line into `.vscode/settings.json` in your project to make use of it.

```
"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
```